# Amazon Alexa error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build an Alexa skill. I am still trying to get Alexa to say something when there is an intent request, but I get an error and I am not sure what to do with it. When I run the Sample Utterance through the Alexa service simulator I get the error:

> The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid.

If I run the same utterance through the lambda test event the error I get is:

> "errorMessage": "Exception: ReferenceError: output is not defined"

My javascript code is

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {

  try {
    //New Session
    if(event.session.new) {
      console.log("NEW SESSION")
    }

    switch (event.request.type) {

      //Launch Request
      case "LaunchRequest":
        console.log(`LAUNCH REQUEST`)
        context.succeed(
          generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse("Welcome to an Alexa Skill, this is running on a lambda function", true),
            {}
          )
        )
        break;

      //Intent Request
      case "IntentRequest":
        console.log(`INTENT REQUEST`)

        switch(event.request.intent.name) {
          case "FindFlight":
            //Get data from user to send to Fare Portal

            //Clean up data to send back to user

            context.succeed(
              generateResponse(
                buildSpeechletResponse("Flight Search", "You asked to find a flight", true),
                {}
              )
            )
            break;

          default:
            throw "Invalid intent"
        }
      break;

      //Session Ended Request
      case "SessionEndedRequest":
        console.log(`SESSION ENDED REQUEST`)
        break;

      default:
        context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`)
    }
  } catch(error) {context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`)}

  //Helpers
  buildSpeechletResponse = (title, outputText, shouldEndSession) => {

    return {
      outputSpeech: {
        type: "PlainText",
        text: outputText
      },
      card: {
          type: 'Simple',
          title: `SessionSpeechlet - ${title}`,
          content: `SessionSpeechlet - ${output}`,
      },
      shoudlEndSession: shouldEndSession
    }
  }

  generateResponse = (sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) => {

    return {
      version: "1.0",
      sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
      response: speechletResponse
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: The second error is as clear as it can get: `output` is indeed not defined. So you need to use variables that are defined or you go ahead and define `output`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a typo in buildSpeechletResponse function:

```
content: `SessionSpeechlet - ${outputText}`,
```